# Diophantine equations involving recurrence sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, recurrences, diophantine-approximation

I am working on a Diophantine equation by using transcendental and reduction methods given by Baker and Davenport. However, when I read some papers i don't understand the reduction step, for example in this paper     (https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.10138), in page 6,
in the step of reduction after putting the linear forms $Z_1$ , I don't understand how have the authors found $e^{|Z_1|}<20$, and why they choosed 20 exactly?
Similarly, in page 7,how have they found $e^{|Z_2|}<2 $ .

Generally, how do we choose the upper bound of $e^{|Z|}$, such that $Z$ is any linear forms of Logarithms in similar cases?

Comment: @GHfromMO many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors skipped some easy steps. By the triangle inequality,
$$e^{z_1}\geq 1-|1-e^{z_1}|>1-0.95=1/20,$$
whence using also $z_1<0$,
$$e^{|z_1|}=e^{-z_1}<20.$$
Similarly,
$$e^{z_2}\geq 1-|1-e^{z_2}|>1-1/2=1/2,$$
whence using also $z_2<0$,
$$e^{|z_2|}=e^{-z_2}<2.$$